# If I lose my job as a first time manager, what steps can I take to bring my career back on track?

Tags: management, career-development, conflict, people-management

I enjoy working with large teams, across teams and coordinating people. I was promoted from team lead to manager because senior boses across the compay recognized that I am good at getting other people to deliver results, coordinate big cross-functional projects, be the face of the organization and take the "big picture" approach.

Unfortunately, I am in conflict with some senior people in my team, facing problems for which I perceive some reasons but have no clear answer. In my deepest gut, I just feel there are personal jealousies at play. But the fact that I cannot deal with this situation makes me feel like my job is at stake...

Should I lose it, for whatever reason, I want to be prepared and still continue on the management path.

However, I am not sure what I did wrong. All my performance reviews were gold medal. My team initially liked me and is even on friendly terms with me. They are also very open with me.
The only thing I know is I cannot trust some of them for how they behave (mentioned numerous times in other questions of mine) and I simply cannot agree with some of their complaints/criticisms.

So - if I was forced to start from scratch in a new company, what would I need to do right from the start to prevent a situation like this to arise?

Comment: Based on what I've seen of your interactions with this site, you are talking _at_ us about your problems rather than _discussing_ your problems with us. If this is how you handle the people you work with then I suspect it is a large part of your problem right there.

Comment: I have seen several good answers being posted to your questions (based on a repetitive theme of relationships with your team/some seniors in the team), have you tried implementing any of those suggestions ? are you able to share how that went ?

Comment: @NewBoss, could you please register so that we can easily find your questions as having new accounts for each question may be upsetting those trying to help you? Thanks.

Comment: Your are *never* going to find out what you did wrong by asking people on a website completely unconnected with the situation. From *your own* descriptions you have done nothing wrong, but they are just your own descriptions and we have no way of finding anyone else's point of view. For the third time today: go and talk to people who can see the whole picture of what is happening in this situation.

Comment: "Talking at us" means you are good at saying things but not very good at listening to replies. It means you are giving usn the information you want us to hear, but not the information we ask for.

Comment: Is there anything in this question which is different from your previous half dozen questions? Is there any point offering an answer and expecting you not to ignore it as you appear to have ignored all the answers to your previous half dozen questions?

Comment: @Carson63000 How do we prevent this continuous spam trail of questions? I see a lot of questions with the same requirement. These questions are coming up for close/reopen votes too many times.

Comment: Obviously not a duplicate. Mods, what are you smoking!

Comment: Plus the duplicate question is also on hold. Mods, could you please actually moderate instead of needless meddling?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that the people on your team are jealous. What are you doing to fix that?

While you give reasons for people to not be upset with you, are you incapable of seeing your mistakes? Are you always the one that can call the shots without offending others? There may be things you **didn't do** that caused issues. When you did get promoted, how did you handle that others may have wanted that position and didn't get it? How do you handle your subordinates that may want a different kind of relationship as I find it close to a contradiction that you state, "They are open with me," and yet you don't trust them which makes me wonder how open are they in that case?

The "talking at us" is likely in reference to how often do you post comments to answers so that things can be clarified so that answers can be improved as what is often asked initially will be revised as more details will be given.